# Setting break via cmd line on running GDB

Tags: c, gdb

Is there a way to set break point via cmd line on using GDB.

Currently on running GDB, I need to set

```
 (gdb) b fun1
 (gdb) b fun2
 (gdb) b fun3
```

and If I close and open the GDB again, I need to set all the  break points :( .
Is there a way to set break point for GDB in cmd line itself, like

```
  $> gdb -break fun1 -break fun2 -break fun3 ./myprog
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

GDB Provides -ex option to set GDB commands such as 'break' 'info' 'set print' 'display x' on invoking GDB from command line, as shown below

```
    $> gdb -ex 'break main' -ex 'info b' -ex 'set print pretty on' ./myprog
```

The option of -ex option is not specified in [man page or in GDB help](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12756)  :(

Comment: good work. this is new to me, and doesn't work on my main machine, gdb version _6.3.5_, so be aware that this appears to be a recent feature.

Answer (score 7):

Put your `break` commands in a file, and pass the file to gdb on the command line using the `-x` flag.

From `man gdb`:

> ```
>    -x file
>            Execute GDB commands from file file.
> ```

It turns out that there **is** a command for similarly passing commands, but on the command line: both `-ex` and `-eval-command` allow you to pass an individual command. It appears to have been introduced in version *7*: it's unavailable on *gdb 6.3.5*, but available in *7.3.1*. `-ex` and `-eval-command` are documented in the online gdb docs with the other command-line arguments [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html#File-Options).

So, for your example:

```
$> gdb -ex 'break fun1' -ex 'break fun2' -ex 'break fun3' ./myprog
```

The other answers schooled me on this.

Comment: It works but I need to keep file :(; No way setting it on cmd line?

Comment: Not very elegant, but a command line: `echo -e b fun1 "\n"b fun2 "\n"b fun3 >/tmp/cmd.tmp ; gdb -x /tmp/cmd.tmp ; rm /tmp/cmd.tmp` @Viswesn

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `gdb -ex 'b fun1' -ex 'b fun2'` (or in long form `-eval-command`).

Curiously, it is missing in `man gdb`, but it is there in `info gdb`. And in the sources, of course!

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know if you can set breakpoints outside gdb, but I know you can use Linux commands inside gdb, so that you don't have to quit gdb frequently. The gdb command is `shell yourcommand`, if u wanna run ls, just type `shell ls` under gdb.